# patching nested formgroup in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

given this form declaration:

```
reactiveForm = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl(),
    lastname: new FormControl(),
    email: new FormControl(),
    gender: new FormControl(),
    isMarried: new FormControl(),
    country: new FormControl(),
    address: new FormGroup({
      city: new FormControl(),
      street: new FormControl(),
      pincode: new FormControl(),
    }),
  });
```

As we know, we can alter the control values via `setValue` or `patchValue`. If we use `setValue`, we have to provide a value for all controls. If we use `patchValue`, we have to provide only values for a subset of controls (for which we want to modify the values).

F. e. in the above case we can use this:

```
patchName() {
    let contact = {
      firstname: 'Rahul',
      lastname: 'Dravid',
    };

    this.reactiveForm.patchValue(contact);
  }
```

It works fine.

Now, if I want to patch `city` and `street` within `address` and use this:

```
patchAddress() {
    let address = {
      city: 'Bangalore',
      street: 'Brigade Road',
    };

    this.reactiveForm.get('address')?.patchValue(address);
  }
```

I get the error `Property 'pincode' is missing in type '{ city: string; street: string; }' but required in type '{ city: any; street: any; pincode: any; }'`.

But if I use it like this:

```
this.reactiveForm.patchValue({ address: address });
```

It works.

So, the question is, why in this case `patchValue` does require all the three properties provided?

I assume, because with `get` I get the strictly typed `address` formgroup with three properties and in this case I have to provide all the three properties in `patchValue`, regardless the fact, that `patchValue` can be used for partial updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "cast" as formGroup, but really I feel that it's a bug

```
(this.reactiveForm.get('address') as FormGroup)?.patchValue(address)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Maybe I will ask it on github.